# Why can't Beetlejuice say his own name?

Tags: movie, cartoon, adaptation-comparison, magical-theory, beetlejuice

Basically what it says in the title:

**Why can't Beetlejuice say his own name?**

The reason I ask is because it seems to be a running theme throughout the franchise---- from the original 1988 film, to the cartoon of the 90s, to the scholastic book series, all the way up to modernized properties like **Beetlejuice: The Musical.**

There seems to be no in-universe reason given for this "unwritten rule" or and it only effects Beetlejuice as a ghost, and not others.

**Background:** For those who don't know, Beetlejuice is the titular character from the Tim Burton 1988 Supernatural Comedy Horror film of the same name:

[image]

Played hilariously by Michael Keaton, Beetlejuice is actually more of the *deuterogamist* of the film, despite being the title character; the main protagonists are actually Adam and Barbara Maitland (the couple pictured in the poster, played very well by Geena Davis and Alec Baldwin). The Maitlands are a sweet-natured "Recently Deceased" couple who end up haunting their own house, which is bought by the nuevoriche Deetz family.

As ghosts, both the Maitlands and Beetlejuice have a variety of supernatural powers... but in most cases, "BJ" is shown to be far, *far* stronger.... or at the very least more proficient: he can alter his form, manipulate objects, cast illusions, teleport, transmogrify himself and others, stop exorcisms, defy gravity, and even seems to have some limited form of matter manipulation.

However, unlike the Maitlands, BJ's power has a condition on it; he seems to have to be "summoned" by someone else saying his name three times; doing so again within his ear-shot seems to have the effect of "calling him off", or forcing him to retreat. In the film, he couldn't even *tell* Lydia his name once, having to have her guess it by a game of charades:

The Maitlands initially took issue with the Deetz's moving in and completely altering their home, so they summon BJ to remove them, but end up forming a parental connection with the daughter, Lydia. As the "Ghost with the Most", BJ is  shown more as "slightly malicious prankster" than actual threat.

**CARTOON and BOOKS**

The cartoon series takes a slightly less maniacal approach; here, BJ and Lydia are best friends, where he seems to have a more "Favorite Uncle-Niece" dynamic with her. He's still a rogue, a troublemaker, scammer and a prankster, but  is shown to have his good points.... most especially, he is **very** protective of Lydia! Most episodes consist of him helping her (or at least trying to) with her problems or bringing her to his Ghostly realm of the "Neither World" for wacky adventures.

[image: https://c.tenor.com/-OqSXl64BpMAAAAC/beetlejuice-lydia.gif]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

In this series BJ is still a pretty powerful specter; he can often transform or make stuff happen even *accidently* ...just by **saying it!** Even here, though, the 3-call-summon/banish and "can't say his own name" rules **still apply.** But again...these are not rules *any other ghost* or supernatural entity from the Netherworld seems to be bound to.

To make things even more complicated, in the stage musical....which largely was adapted from the movie.... a whole song is dedicated to BJ basically trying to get Lydia to say his name and summon him the first time. Yes....apparently, there is a musical.

Is there perhaps some kind of "negative effect" on BJ if he was to say his name himself?

Comment: Most of this question seems unneeded. Everything from "Background" down should be deleted.

Comment: @Valorum I gave the examples because this is a long-running franchise with different formats. As we know, it's not uncommon for everything from in-story rules to character appearances to abilities to be altered in different formats. Across all these media though, despite various other changes, these rules seem to remain _very_ consistent.  It's not unreasonable to think someone may have seen one but not the others, and then show where they didn't hold up. So I was just being thorough. while also showing I am open to answers from any of these sources... and that I _did_ do my initial research.

Comment: Research is fine, but as I've said before, when you do an info-dump like this it detracts from the question being asked. Brevity something something.

Comment: @Valorum Edited.  kept the important points: Notable power differences between him and the Maitlands in the movie, no one else being bound by the name rules, central differences in the cartoon and books that _still_ holds to the main rules, and got rid of some of the supplemental question aspects.

Comment: looks like in the shooting script there's a little more info given by Juno the Maitlands: "He was demoted to a Grade-6 malevolent spirit.  He's been imprisoned on that plane ever since... in fact, I believe he's been sleezing around your cemetery lately.  He can only be brought back by saying his name three times." - the final cut of the film doesn't include the 'demoted' and imprisoned part. So - perhaps the name thing was intended to be part of the punishement / 'magic' keeping him locked away - https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/beetlejuice_skaaren_final.html

Comment: @NKCampbell Well damn, that's good to know it has an in-story reason, at least in movie (assuming the demotion made it like that.) But then...if he's a _lesser_ spirit, how is he portrayed as being so much more _powerful_ in his techniques than Adam, Barbara, and any other ghost we see in the film?

Comment: we only really see Adam and Barbara, and they clearly need coaching and assistance to even get where they are. We aren't given much about Juno's powers but she seems to be more 'powerful' than the Maitlands (able to disappear at will, transport them back to their house, etc...). Juno doesn't say that she can't handle Beets, just that she recommends that *they* don't mess with him

Comment: @NKCampbell This was why I pointed out these seeming power difference in the movie. However, even with the other ghost present, some who have been dead as long, we never see them coming anywhere _near_ BJ's power, so even with a "demotion"....which, I'd theorize, only made the whole Name Rule go into effect.... he's still somewhat above the other spirits in the film. This difference is more evident in the cartoon, where he's one of the few supernatural beings who can pull of what he does _all_ the time.

Comment: personally, I wouldn't really consider the cartoon 'canon' in comparison to the movie. Maybe an alternate timeline at best. It bears very little relation to the movie other than character names and a couple of costumes.

Comment: All of the rules that govern his existence are arbitrary. Whatever reason he can only be summoned by saying his name three times is the same reason he can’t say his name. If he could, he could just summon himself and do whatever he wants.

Comment: @NKCampbell I see your point, but given it's the longer running part of the franchise, we can't just disregard it, especially as it offers examples of the rules in effect. Same argument could be made for the books and play, even though the original creator had little to do with those as well.

Comment: @ToddWilcox While your point is factual, it's relevance is relative; it's like saying "they could just say anything in the movie and it sticks"....which again, _does_ ring true. But then, it makes the whole point of _having_ the rule in the first place meaningless. In a meta sense, I get it: the film needed something that could limit his scope, or like you said...he'd just do whatever he wanted. and a character with no limits isn't much of one, not without _some_ catch. My thing is, the rule itself is fine, but are we, as the audience, ever given a **reason** for the rule? That's the question

Comment: I would assume that Beetlejuice is prohibited from saying his own name so he cannot release himself from the nether world.